# Theming in react and sass

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I am trying to change the theme in this file programatically, I have tried to read about mixins but I realized that would cause a lot of change in my whole project. Any suggestion of how to change the theme based on a variable which the user selects?

```
// Default
@import "default/variables";

// Green
@import "green/variables";

// lavander
// @import "lavander/variables";
```